# Flex ResourceBundle get keys -> `content` doesn't provide key-value pairs any more

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, resourcebundle

I need to access key-value pairs from a properties file, well a substring of the key and the value to be exact, but that shouldn't change anything.

When you check the Adobe docs and help pages such as this one http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f2c.html (last paragraph) you can see that Adobe mentions that the ResourceBundle's content property contains key-value pairs from the given bundle.

The ASDoc of the ResourceBundle also says: 
"The subclass overrides this method to return an Object that contains key-value pairs for the bundle's resources."
However, the ASDoc also says that this property applies for Flex 3.

Anyway, the content property (type Object) doesn't seem to store key-value pairs, as I only get the value, not the key though.

I'm kinda lost here, if anyone has some information regarding this, please shoot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASDoc for `ResourceBundle` says that this class and it's API is available since Flex 3. So the documentation is still valid for Flex 4 and beyond.

Make sure you are using a "for in" loop rather than a "for each" loop. The "for in" loop iterates over the property names of an Object, while the "for each" would iterate over the values.

This code creates a `ResourceBundle` and iterates over the properties:

```
var rb:ResourceBundle = new ResourceBundle("en_US", "bundleName");
rb.content["foo"] = "Bar";
rb.content["hello"] = "Howdy!";

for (var key:String in rb.content)
{
    trace("the key is: ", key);
    trace("the value is: ", rb.content[key]);
}
```

While iterating, each key is stored in the var `key` and it's value can be retrieved from the content Object using `content[key]`.

In a real application, w/a real resource bundle file, you retrieve the resource bundle from the resource manager (from the docs you linked to):

```
var rb:ResourceBundle =  ResourceBundle(resourceManager.getResourceBundle("en_US", "RegistrationForm"))
```

And then you should be able to iterate over it's content as above.

Comment: My code had exactly the problem you described, a `for each` loop instead of a simple `for`. Works as it should now. Thank you so very much!